# Como fazer README.md multilinguagem para Github?

Tags: github

Em um dos meus projetos no git, o arquivo `README.md` está em inglês, então eu fiz outro chamado `README-pt.md` e um link para navegar entre eles, [por exemplo](https://github.com/anisanwesley/anisan-college/tree/master/Anisoket):

```
[Read this page in English](http....README.md)
[Leia esta página em português](http....README-pt.md)
```

Mas há uma forma de fazer isso dinamicamente, em que ele abra a lingua correta de acordo com quem está acessando?

Comment: Já experimentou obter o idioma do navegador com JS? Não estou certo até que ponto a interpretação de HTML é aceita, isso pra não dizer sem fundamentos que o Jekyll trata os MDs do Github como texto plano.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Não existe uma forma para se fazer isso no Github, não há interpretação para i8n no mesmo. A forma que você seguiu é a mais correta.

Comment: Que pena.. bom, vou fazer o seguinte então, algo como: `Select Language : [English], [Portuguese]`, que vai ser estático no cabeçalho de cada readme, simulando um menu. Obrg.